# d3 how to manipulate svg translate value

Tags: d3.js, svg

```
var g = d3.select("#originalRectElement");
d3.select('#newElem').append('path').attr('transform', g.attr('transform'));
```

here I am creating a new "path" and setting the transform value from #originalRectElement.

I want to add 10px more to the x-axis of the transform value (which is for example translate(100,100)). How can I set that using d3.js?

I want the output as translate(110,100). How can I set that using d3.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this:

```
var g = d3.select("#originalRectElement");

d3.select('#newElem').append('path').attr('transform', function() {
    var transform = g.attr('transform');
    var offsets = transform .match(/(\d+)/g); // We grab only the digits    

    return 'translate(' + (offsets[0] + 10) + ',' + offsets[1] + ')'; // Here we add 10 to the x offset
});
```

The idea is quite simple: use a `regex` to grab the `x`,`y` values in the `transform` attribute, then  return the new offsets.

Comment: thats the hack I have in place right now...My thoughts were are there any better built in method or function within d3?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `d3.transform` [method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#d3_transform).

```
var trans = d3.transform(g.attr('transform')).translate;
whatEver.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (trans[0] + 10) + ',' + trans[1] + ')');
```